# Efficiently performing elementwise operation using coordinates on scipy sparse array

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently do the following operation on a scipy sparse array (csc format):

Elementwise pseudocode:

```
try:
    r = M[i,j] / (V[i] + V[j])
    if r.isfinite():
        M[i,j] = r
    else:
        # Leave at old value
        pass # e.g. 1e200/1e-200 -> inf
except ZeroDivisionError:
    # Leave at old value
    pass # e.g. 1e200/0 -> ZeroDivisionError
```

Note that this leaves zero elements as 0, and so does not increase the density of the input matrix `M`.

There's a straightforward approach for a dense matrix:

```py
# V is a ndarray of shape (N), all values finite and >= 0.0
# M is a ndarray of shape (N,N), all values finite

rows_plus_cols = V[:, np.newaxis] + V[np.newaxis, :]
M = np.divide(M, rows_plus_cols, out=M, where=(rows_plus_cols != 0))
```

(Note that this example does not handle underflow properly in all cases.)

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't appear to work for a sparse matrix, because the intermediate calculation of `rows_plus_cols` results in a dense matrix of size `(N,N)`.

A typical input M might be 100k by 100k, with ~1M nonzero entries. Decidedly in the regime where materializing a full dense matrix is ill-advised. For testing purposes, the following is 'close enough' to typical inputs:

```py
n = 100000
d = 10
# a.k.a. "mostly nonzero, but not always"
V = np.maximum((np.random.normal(size=n)+2), 0)

M = scipy.sparse.csc_array((np.random.normal(size=n*d), np.random.randint(n, size=(2, n*d))), shape=(n,n))
M.sum_duplicates()
M.prune()
M.sort_indices()
```

Minor problem: scipy sparse arrays don't appear to allow elementwise division with a `where` clause. Can be worked around, but that's not the main issue. I know that you can access the underlying datapoints of a scipy csc array with `M.data`; I do not see how to do an elementwise calculation *that is a function of the coordinates* without materializing a dense matrix.

Suggestions?

Comment: with `csc` yoou can use the `indptr` abd `indices` arrays access all nonzero indices of `M`

Comment: How do I go from there to coordinates in a somewhat-efficient manner?

Comment: no sparse is efficient without compiliing. The COO method is easier to describe and understand.  CSR/CSC uses matrix multiplication fot most indexing tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way you could do this with a `coo_array`.

In this example, `M` is an 8x8 `coo_array`, and `V` is a 1-d NumPy array with length 8.  If `M` might have duplicate entries, you should call `M.sum_duplicates()` before doing the following.

```
In [106]: M
Out[106]: 
<8x8 sparse array of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 16 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [107]: M.toarray()
Out[107]: 
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.44, 0.  , 0.93, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.54, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.2 , 0.21, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.93, 0.76, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.32, 0.88, 0.76],
       [0.91, 0.72, 0.  , 0.24, 0.87, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.74, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.13, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])

In [108]: M.data
Out[108]: array([0.44, 0.93, 0.54, 0.2 , 0.21, 0.93, 0.76, 0.32, 0.88, 0.76, 0.91, 0.72, 0.24, 0.87, 0.74, 0.13])

In [109]: M.row
Out[109]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7], dtype=int32)

In [110]: M.col
Out[110]: array([2, 4, 6, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3], dtype=int32)

In [111]: V
Out[111]: array([0.5, 1. , 2. , 0. , 0. , 0.5, 1. , 0. ])
```

First form the denominator as `V[M.row] + V[M.col]`, and replace any occurrences of 0 with 1, so instead of dividing by 0, the value at those location remains unchanged:

```
In [112]: denom = V[M.row] + V[M.col]

In [113]: denom[denom == 0] = 1

In [114]: denom
Out[114]: array([2.5, 0.5, 2. , 2. , 2.5, 0.5, 1. , 0.5, 1. , 1. , 1. , 1.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1. , 1. ])
```

We'll call the new array `Q`.  `Q_data` will be the `data` array of `Q`:

```
In [115]: Q_data = M.data / denom

In [116]: Q_data
Out[116]: array([0.176, 1.86 , 0.27 , 0.1  , 0.084, 1.86 , 0.76 , 0.64 , 0.88 , 0.76 , 0.91 , 0.48 , 0.48 , 1.74 , 0.74 , 0.13 ])
```

Create a new `coo_array` with `Q_data`, using the same shape and same row and column indices as `M`:

```
In [117]: Q = sparse.coo_array((Q_data, (M.row, M.col)), shape=M.shape)

In [118]: Q.toarray()
Out[118]: 
array([[0.   , 0.   , 0.176, 0.   , 1.86 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.27 , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.1  , 0.084, 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.86 , 0.76 , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.64 , 0.88 , 0.76 ],
       [0.91 , 0.48 , 0.   , 0.48 , 1.74 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.74 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.13 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]])
```

Do the dense version of the calculation to verify that it worked as expected:

```
In [119]: VV = np.add.outer(V, V)

In [120]: VV[VV == 0] = 1

In [121]: M.toarray() / VV
Out[121]: 
array([[0.   , 0.   , 0.176, 0.   , 1.86 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.27 , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.1  , 0.084, 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.86 , 0.76 , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.64 , 0.88 , 0.76 ],
       [0.91 , 0.48 , 0.   , 0.48 , 1.74 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.74 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.13 , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   , 0.   ]])
```

You can take lines 112, 113, 115 and 117 of that ipython session and wrap them up as a function.

Comment: So much easier with COO arrays, isn't it. Alas, my input is a CSC array. Or are you suggesting `tocoo() -> this -> tocsc()`?

Comment: (As an aside: that `denominator == 0` trick does not work in all cases. Consider `10/5e-324`.)

Comment: Oops--I saw `M = scipy.sparse.coo_array((...` in your example, and didn't scroll to the end of the line to see `..., shape=(n,n)).tocsc()`!

Comment: Instead of `denominator == 0`, you could use any calculation that results in a `bool` array, e.g. `denominator < np.finfo(np.float64).tiny` if you want [subnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormal_number) values to be treated like 0.

Comment: *"Or are you suggesting `tocoo() -> this -> tocsc()`?"*  That would certainly work.

Comment: I've updated the question to better-reflect the desired infinity behavior (roughly: don't update if result would be +- inf, regardless of cause). I keep forgetting that division can result in +- inf without a ZeroDivisionError...

Comment: I've updated the question to directly construct a csc_array in the example, to hopefully reduce confusion.

Comment: It's not just subnormals, e.g. `1e200/1e-200 -> inf`.

Comment: That's true, but your example with `try/except` had the same problem.  The updated question now clarifies the desired behavior.

Comment: As I said, I keep forgetting that division can result in +- inf without a ZeroDivisionError. That being said, the general approach (convert to COO / do elementwise operation on data/row/col / convert back) appears to work, so I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: I dealt with the infinity issue by masking where the result was non-finite.